# Update column with values of array sequentially

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table to which I added a new column 'color'. Now I would like to update all the existing rows to have a one of three colors ('#F00', '#0F0', '#00F') and sequentially.

So first row would be #F00, second #0F0, third #00F and fourth again #F00 etc.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET color = oneOf(['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F']);
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Is there any column that represents the order (`first row`,`second  row`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MariaDB version support window function, you can try to use an order column (in my sample code is `ID` column) that represents the order  for your update sequentially

Then use `CASE WHEN` expression & `MOD` function to judgment update logic

```
UPDATE
    table_name AS t
INNER JOIN
    ( 
      SELECT Id, 
             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rn 
      FROM table_name
    ) AS sub
ON  t.Id = sub.Id
SET color = (CASE WHEN MOD(rn,3) = 1 THEN '#F00'
                 WHEN MOD(rn,3) = 2 THEN '#0F0'
                 ELSE '#00F' END)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a27f569d6277db94f2f8e0db3ea009be)